# extracting file content inside multiple folders and printing required folder names

Tags: python-3.x, file, data-extraction

I have files and directory structure like this:

```
C:\data\4512\required_data\121\a.txt
C:\data\4512\required_data\121\b.txt
C:\data\4512\required_data\456\c.txt
C:\data\4512\required_data\456\d.txt

C:\data\9813\required_data\789\e.txt
C:\data\9813\required_data\789\f.txt
C:\data\9813\required_data\301\g.txt
C:\data\9813\required_data\301\h.txt
```

I want to print the content of the text files
Also I want to print outer_folder number like 4512, inner folder number like 121 and the file name

I was trying some code like this:

```
path = "C:\\data"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for dir in dirs:
        print(dir)
        data_location = os.path.join(path, dir, "required_data")
```

for example, for this case:

```
C:\data\4512\required_data\121\a.txt
```

Expected output:

```
file=open("a.txt")
print(file) # content of file
print("outer_number") # 4512
print("inner_number") # 121
print("name_of_file") # a.txt
```

I want to do this for all files